How to implement navigation logic inside a Modal Drawer in Jetpack Compose
I am tryng to implement the navigation of my app with the modal drawer component of Jetpack Compose, but i dont know if I am doing it in the right way, so i need feedback about it.
I was tryng this logic replacing the content of my scaffold which is also inside the modal drawer:
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    val state by homeViewModel.state.collectAsState()
    val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    HandleHomeNavigationLogout(homeViewModel, navHostController, state)
    HandleAlertDialogs(homeViewModel, state)
    HandleErrorDialogs(homeViewModel, state)

    HomeContentModalDrawer(
        navHostController = navHostController,
        state = state,
        homeViewModel = homeViewModel,
        scope = scope,
        drawerState = drawerState
    )
}

@Composable
private fun HandleHomeNavigationLogout(
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel,
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    state: HomeState
){
    if (state.navigateToLoginAfterLogout) {
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            navHostController.navigate(AuthRoute.LogIn.route) {
                popUpTo("main_graph") {
                    inclusive = true
                }
            }
            homeViewModel.onEvent(HomeEvent.NavigateToLoginHandled)
        }
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
private fun HomeContentModalDrawer(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navHostController: NavHostController,
    state: HomeState,
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel,
    scope: CoroutineScope,
    drawerState: DrawerState
) {

    ModalNavigationDrawer(
        drawerContent = {
            NavDrawer(
                userFullName = "${state.currentUserName} ${state.currentUserLastName}",
                onCloseDrawer = {
                    scope.launch { drawerState.close() }
                    homeViewModel.onEvent(HomeEvent.CloseDrawer)
                },
                onItemSelected = { item ->
                    scope.launch { drawerState.close() }
                    homeViewModel.onEvent(HomeEvent.DrawerItemSelected(item))
                    homeViewModel.navigateTo(item.itemName.lowercase())
                },
                selectedItemScreen = state.selectedScreen
            )
        },
        drawerState = drawerState
    ) {
        Scaffold(
            topBar = {
                TopAppBar(
                    title = {
                        Text(
                            text = state.selectedScreen.itemName, // ${state.businessName}
                            style = Typography.titleMedium,
                            fontSize = 20.sp
                        )
                    },
                    navigationIcon = {
                        IconButton(onClick = {
                            scope.launch { drawerState.open() }
                            homeViewModel.onEvent(HomeEvent.OpenDrawer)
                        }) {
                            Icon(
                                Icons.Default.Menu,
                                contentDescription = "NavMenu",
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    colors = TopAppBarColors(
                        containerColor = Blue80,
                        titleContentColor = Color.White,
                        navigationIconContentColor = Color.White,
                        actionIconContentColor = Color.White,
                        scrolledContainerColor = Color.Transparent
                    )
                )
            }
        ) { paddingValues ->
            Box(
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(paddingValues)
            ) {
                //
                when (state.selectedScreen.itemName.lowercase()) {
                    "inicio" -> AttendanceScreen()
                    "reportes" -> StatsScreen()
                    "empleados" -> WorkersScreen(
                        navController = navHostController
                    )
                    "sincronizar" -> SyncScreen()
                    "configuración" -> SettingsScreen()
                    "acerca de" -> AboutScreen()
                    //
                    //
                    //"cerrar sesión" -> { homeViewModel.onEvent(HomeEvent.ShowLogoutDialog) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun HandleErrorDialogs(
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel,
    state: HomeState
) {
    if (state.errorMessage?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
        LaunchedEffect(state.errorMessage) {
            delay(3000)
            homeViewModel.onEvent(HomeEvent.DismissErrorMessage)
        }
        ErrorDialog(
            errorMessage = state.errorMessage,
            onDismiss = { homeViewModel.onEvent(HomeEvent.DismissErrorMessage) }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
private fun HandleAlertDialogs(
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel,
    state: HomeState
) {
    if (state.showLogoutDialog) {
        LogoutDialog(
            showDialog = state.showLogoutDialog,
            onConfirm = { homeViewModel.onEvent(HomeEvent.ConfirmLogout) },
            onDismiss = { homeViewModel.onEvent(HomeEvent.DismissLogoutDialog) }
        )
    }
}

And the method that I used in the viewmodel is this one, managed by the state of this screen also.
    fun navigateTo(screen: String) {
        val selectedItem = getDrawerItemForScreen(screen)
        _state.update { it.copy(selectedScreen = selectedItem) }
    }

    private fun getDrawerItemForScreen(screen: String): DrawerItem {
        return when (screen.lowercase()) {
            "inicio" -> DrawerItem(Icons.Default.Home, "Inicio")
            "reportes" -> DrawerItem(Icons.Default.Equalizer, "Reportes")
            "empleados" -> DrawerItem(Icons.Default.People, "Empleados")
            "sincronizar" -> DrawerItem(Icons.Default.Sync, "Sincronizar")
            "configuración" -> DrawerItem(Icons.Default.Settings, "Configuración")
            "acerca de" -> DrawerItem(Icons.Default.Info, "Acerca de")
            "cerrar sesión" -> DrawerItem(Icons.AutoMirrored.Filled.Logout, "Cerrar sesión")
            else -> DrawerItem(Icons.Default.Home, "Inicio")
        }
    }

So if anyone knows how to do it better, I would appreciate your opinions.
